# merge two sorted array without extra space . showing wrong output

Tags: arrays, sorting, binary-search

my code is working fine on online gdb compiler and my local vscode compiler but when i am trying to submit it on geeksforgeeks it is showing garbage value in one or sometimes two array elements ( and if i try compiling it over and over sometimes correct output shows up)
Expected output -:- 2 3 5 7 8 8 14 16
output on gfg -:- -399714115 -357445888 2 3 5 8 14 16 
i tried dry run of my code but still unable to understand where this output is coming from. 
Thanks for helping

```
void swap(int* a,int* b)
{
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

//returns the position where k should fit....Ex- k=5 a[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7}
//returns pos=3 
int binary_search(int a[],int n,int k)
{
    int low=0;
    int high=n;
    int mid;
    // int index;
    while(high>=low)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(a[mid]<k && a[mid+1]>=k)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if(a[mid]<k)
        {
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            high=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return mid;
}

class Solution{
public:
    void merge(int a[], int b[], int n, int m) {
        int pos=n-1;
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;--i)
        {
            pos=binary_search(b,pos,a[i]);
            int smaller=pos+1;
            
            if(smaller>n-i)
                continue;
                
            int j,k;
            for(j=0,k=n-1;(j<smaller || k>=i);++j,--k)
            {
                swap(&b[j],&a[k]);
            }
            break;
        }
        sort(a,a+n);
        sort(b,b+m);
        // for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        // {
        //     cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        // }
        // cout<<endl;
        // for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
        // {
        //     cout<<b[i]<<" ";
        // }
    }
};
```

Comment: `if(a[mid]<k && a[mid+1]>=k) { return mid; }` This is a bit surprising - if for instance `a[mid+1] == k`, shouldn't the binary search return `mid+1` and not `mid`?

Comment: `if(a[mid]<=k) { low=mid+1; }` And now if `a[mid] == k`, then you'll set `low=mid+1` and miss the position `mid`.

Comment: Your function `Solution::merge` is calling a function `sort` which you didn't include in your post.

Comment: @Stef  thanks for the remarks . I have made changes acc. to first and second comment but it is still showing the same problem (and sort() is the STL function)